# Seeing PHP variables in files loaded using AJAX

Tags: php, ajax

If I have a PHP page that contains the following:

`<?php $showLink = true; ?>`

and then using AJAX load in some content with the following:

```
<?php if($showLink ) { ?>
    <a href="#">This link should appear if the variable exists</a>
    <?php } ?>
```

The loaded page cannot see the variable in the parent page... Any ideas why?

I've tried using both sessions and define and the same problem happens, and also tried setting the cache to false in the ajax settings.

Really confused about this...

Comment: I could not understand what you meant by `The loaded page cannot see the variable in the parent page... Any ideas why?`

Comment: When you call some php script using ajax new php process is started, so variable in previous process is inaccessible for this process. Sessions must work fine. Can you show, how have you tried?

Comment: @asprin He probably gets `Undefined variable`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['showLink'] = true; ?>
```

and

```
<?php
session_start();
 if($_SESSION['showLink']) { ?>
    <a href="#">This link should appear if the variable exists</a>
 <?php } ?>
```

Comment: I actually figured this out before you posted but I'll give you acceptance seen as you answered correctly :)

Answer (score 2):

Just pass `$showLink` as a parameter when doing the AJAX call. Then process that variable in the server side script that you called with AJAX.

**Edit:** This is the best recommendation I can give without seeing the actual source code or having more information.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 

if($showLink == true) {
  echo '<a href="#">This link should appear if the variable exists</a>';
} 

?>
```

you don't need to close and reopen the php tags. And you need to actually compare the variable, or if you want to check if it exists use `isset($showLink)`

That's all I can really say given what you've shown.